# Can we share the Go Pass?

Tags: budget, public-transport, belgium

We are a group of friends and will be visiting a few places in Belgium. So we wanted to buy `Go Pass` as they are cheaper. But we will not be able to make 10 trips between 2 stations per person. [This](http://www.b-rail.be/nat-r/E/tarifs/passes/go/)  website says that: `so you can lend it to friends or travel with them`.

I just want to be sure that it means the following: If we are going from station A to B then 2/3 friends can travel with **one** `Go Pass` and make 2/3 entries in `Go Pass` respectively.

Comment: I agree that this is not really clearly defined. Even with the Dutch version I am not completely sure. http://www.b-rail.be/nat/N/tarifs/passes/go/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes,

the Go Pass allows you to share across multiple people. [According to the Belgian Rail website](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/passes-cards/go-pass-10.aspx), it is basically 10 tickets to be used on any ride within Belgium, by anyone under 26. There is no name written on the tickets so it could really be used by anyone: they clearly say `Up to 10 people on 1 Go Pass`.

They stress the fact that as you fill it yourself (writing the date and departure/arrival), [you should not make mistake](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/travel-tickets/passes-cards/complete-pass.aspx) as it could be misinterpreted as cheating (they recommend to use another line if you make a mistake, i.e. another of the 10 rides)

Comment: Note that all the persons sharing one pass have to meet the age criterion: less than 26 years old.

Comment: You can indeed travel with several persons on one pass. You fill out one line on it per person. Young people do this all the time. Do however pay attention to the way dates are written in Belgium: It's "Day-Month-Year". If you do this wrong you could end up paying a fine for travelling with an invalid ticket.

Comment: Furthermore, make sure you fill it in BEFORE boarding the train.